# Robot lidar filter, ros2

Tags: ros2, lidar, robot, filter

I saw that for ROS1 there is this [local filter](https://wiki.ros.org/robot_body_filter) for the lidar scan that is masking the robot shape, there is something similar for ROS2?
From what I saw there isn't.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can make a simple filter that hides the robot structure from the laser scan data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how simple it is. I had a friend which used PCL library to filter out undesired point cloud data (the shovel from of a backhoe). I don't have his code, but I saw his presentation...

Steps he has done:

1. Receive Lidar Data: Subscribe to **/lidar_points** to get the raw point
   cloud data from the lidar sensor.
2. Transform Point Cloud: Optionally, adjust the point cloud to a
   **common reference frame**, like the base frame of the robot, if needed to accurately locate the shovel part.
3. Define Shovel's Structure: Use a simple geometric shape to represent
   the shovel's area in the point cloud. This doesn't have to be
   complex; a basic shape like a box or cylinder that approximates the
   shovel's volume works.
4. Filter Out the Shovel: Apply a PCL filter, such as **pcl::CropBox**,
   configured with the shovel's geometric shape to remove those points
   from the point cloud. Adjust the filter's parameters to match the
   shovel's location and dimensions.
5. Publish Cleaned Data: **Output the filtered point cloud** to a topic
   like /cloud_filtered for use in further processing or analysis.

Example of code (Chat GPT generated)

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/crop_box.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2.h>

void filter_shovel_from_pointcloud(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr& input_cloud_msg) {
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); // Original point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); // Filtered point cloud
    
    // Convert ROS2 PointCloud2 message to PCL point cloud
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input_cloud_msg, *cloud);

    // Define the CropBox filter to remove the shovel
    pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZ> boxFilter;
    boxFilter.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(x_min, y_min, z_min, 1.0)); // Set the min corner of the box
    boxFilter.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(x_max, y_max, z_max, 1.0)); // Set the max corner of the box
    boxFilter.setInputCloud(cloud);
    boxFilter.setNegative(true); // True removes the points inside the box
    boxFilter.filter(*cloud_filtered);

    // Convert filtered PCL point cloud back to ROS2 PointCloud2 message
    sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 output_cloud_msg;
    pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_filtered, output_cloud_msg);
    output_cloud_msg.header.frame_id = input_cloud_msg->header.frame_id; // Preserve frame ID
    
    // Publish the filtered point cloud (you need to set up a publisher for this)
    // publisher_->publish(output_cloud_msg);
}
```

x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, and z_max are the coordinates which define the bounding box around the shovel.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no ready to use robot_body_filter ported to ROS2. You will need to hard code!

PCL library: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl

Usage of this library (Planar segmentation, voxel grid filter, etc):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcCsN_JSHoQ